# how to make JTextField input accessable in other classes

Tags: java, swing, jtextfield

I am trying to make my JTextField input visible to my other classes. I am not going to clog up the page with a ton of code, just where the problem is.

I have done a ton of online research but I am getting nowhere.

```
public class browseropen extends JFrame { 

    public browseropen() {
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE); // setting app close on exit 
        JPanel panel = new JPanel(); // creating new app panel

        JTextField urltxt = new JTextField(10); // establishing new text field for URL input
        urltxt.addActionListener(new ActionListener() { // adding event for enter key
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event ) {
                runClient();              // run browser open command
            }
        });

        public String geturltxt() { // attempting to set input of JTextField to be available in other class

                    return urltxt.getText();

                }
```

I would appreciate any insight as I am just starting to learn Java and want to learn the right way :)

Edit: the problem is in geturltxt

Comment: You could make the JTextField a class field and add a getter for it. As an extra note: Java class names should be PascalCase.

Comment: @GhostCat I should've posted my comment as an answer, I would've been minutes before you ;)

Comment: @Thibstars Just to be sure: I didn't need to read your comment in order to get my answer down ;-) ... but you have been compensated. Merry holidays ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easy answer is: turn that local variable into a **field** of your class, like

```
public class BrowserOpen extends JFrame {
  private final JTextField urltxt; // to be init'ed in your constructor for example
```

And voila, now your other methods can use that **field** urltxt.

Notes: please read about java coding styleguides to get your class/field names "right".

Comment: so I would add `urltxt urltext = new JTextField();` to my browseropen()

Comment: Exactly. But beyond that: you probably want to step back from UI coding for a bit of further learning. You know "fields" versus "variables" is **super basic** stuff. And if you dont know about such things, you better **learn** about them first. In other words: consider learning to crawl before trying to run. Swing UI programming is a **complicated** undertaking - and it seems that you are not ready for that (yet).